# MATLAB doesn't show help for user-created class private methods and properties

Tags: matlab, oop, documentation, private-members

This is the problem:

1. Create a class and set the access to be private for some of the properties or methods.
2. Use the `doc` command for the created class. This will auto-generate documentation from your comments and show it in the built-in help browser.

   `doc classname`

The problem is that documentation for the private properties and methods is not shown in the help browser. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: What is your use case? In general, private methods are only used internally by the class itself and cannot be accessed from the outside. In other words: users can't see it, can't use it, so there's no need to know about the very existence of the method (let alone how to use it). It's one of the principles of encapsulation. Any documentation is for developer's eyes only, and can thus be left in the code.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is intended to be used by other developers. From what I see this it the best way to include the documentation for the source code.
I can't see the reason why would documentation hide the private methods and properties as MATLAB source files can be seen by anyone. This is documentation, not the code. I can't see why MATLAB follows rules of OOP paradigm in the documentation.

Comment: If you're distributing MATLAB code to end users, you would typically want them to only see documentation for functionality that they can directly access, and not be confused by implementation details such as private methods. If developers want to see more details, they can look at the code itself. MATLAB source files can not necessarily be seen by anyone - you can `pcode` them.

Comment: I've been looking at this because the help command shows the same behavior, and I can see that being useful to my coworkers, for instance `help class.PrivateMethod`. @Amro 's solution gave me hope, but it didn't work out, twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I spent like 10 minutes using the debugger, jumping from one function to the next, tracing the execution path of a simple `doc MyClass` call.

Eventually it lead me to the following file:

```
fullfile(toolboxdir('matlab'),'helptools','+helpUtils','isAccessible.m')
```

This function is called during the process of generating documentation for a class to determine if the class elements (including methods, properties, and events) are publicly accessible and non-hidden. This information is used later on to "cull" the elements.

So if you are willing to modify MATLAB's internal functions, and you want the docs to always show all methods and properties regardless of their scope, just rewrite the function to say:

```
function b = isAccessible(classElement, elementKeyword)
    b = true;
    return

    % ... some more code we'll never reach!
end
```

Of course, don't forget to make a backup of the file in case you changed your mind later :)

*(on recent Windows, you'll need to perform this step with administrative privileges)*

---

As a test, take the sample class defined in [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-help-for-classes.html#br_jrwg-1) and run `doc someClass`. The result:

[image: doc someClass]

Comment: I think that in R2015a the isAccessible file doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I did some hunting, and for the sake of Googlers here is where the file is now: `fullfile(toolboxdir('matlab'),'general','+matlab','+internal','+language','+introspective','isAccessible.m')`

Comment: @Hovestar: thanks for the update, things sometimes do change from release to release...

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is by design - the auto-generated documentation is intended for users of the class, who would only be able to access the public properties and methods.

There's no way that I'm aware of to change this behaviour.

You could try:

1. Use an alternative system of auto-generating documentation such as [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab) from the MATLAB Central File Exchange (which I believe will document all properties, not just public).
2. Implement your own `doc` command. Your `doc` command should accept exactly the same inputs as the built-in `doc` command, detect if its inputs correspond to your class/methods/properties etc, and if so display their documentation, otherwise pass its inputs straight through to the built-in `doc`. Make sure your command is ahead of the built-in on the path.

Comment: I did the hard work and I isolated the function responsible for testing whether methods/properties are public or not. See my answer